# How to disable prettier for a single line in SaSS/CSS

Tags: sass, prettier

I generally want Prettier to strip of the leading zero from units in SaSS/CSS but, in a specific SaSS mixin test, I need to retain the leading zero.

I have tried:

```
/* prettier-ignore */
font-size: 0.8889rem;
```

Upon saving the file, the leading zero is still be removed. Is there a way to tell Prettier to ignore a specific line or say, ignore the following block?

```
/* prettier-ignore */
@include expect {
    font-size: 16px;
     font-size: 0.88889rem;
}
```

Comment: Add a hyphen? `/* prettier-ignore */`

Comment: Whoops, my bad. That is a typo, I do have it with the hyphen.

Comment: And are you sure it's Prettier that's removing the leading zero. You're not running any other tools for formatting/linting like styelint?

Comment: 100% sure. If I disable the Prettier plugin in Atom, it is no longer removed.

Comment: Well it's probably not Prettier that's removing leading zeros, my guess is stylelint or something similar. https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEABAllMAbArgEzgAI4APABzjBiOAB0oimiAzaGAWgGd0AvOJEQCMANnKkA3A2at23PgKIAGAHQAODWoCcAJzgBbKVAC+IADQgI5GOmhdkoAIY6dEAO4AFZwnspHANwh0fHMQACMdRzAAazgYAGVyKMwAc2QYHVw4CwALGH1sAHUc9HguJLA4eJ9S9H9SgE9kcC57C0wuOB0YD0iU-UdkFkdsTosAKy5SACFImLj4x304ABlMOCGRsZBJ0njU7DgARVwIeE3R7JAknU6dZq4wVtDyHUwYQuCYHOQ1JQtXhBOoVIuRmq84Hd-BsLHoAI64dB6XqOfqDJDDS4WTr6dDpTJXHhQFKHE5nDYYrZXGCOMKffDfZAAJgsGUc6GwqQAwhB9ANmlBoDCQLhOgAVWm+TGdYzGIA

Comment: Hmmm, that does indeed seem to suggest it is not Prettier. Will have to do some more digging. As mentioned though, when I disable the Prettier plugin, the behaviour described stops. Perhaps it is Prettier working in tandem with Stylelint?

Comment: I'm not using Atom, but the Prettier plugin for VSCode has a boolean option to co-op with stylelint. Check the plugin settings and/or Atom settings

Comment: @schalkneethling did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue in regards to a linebreak that I need to not break in a scss file.

Answer (score 5):

Ok I was playing around with this and I found out a weird quirk with prettier and Sass.

This doesn't work, and will auto linebreak after the comment:

```
.class {
// prettier-ignore
  /* Comment to not format */right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

But this does and will keep all lines of the class in tact:

```
// prettier-ignore
.class {
  /* Comment to not format */right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

It doesn't reproduce your exact problem but it does show how sometimes the ignore comment won't work as expected. Basically the ignore has to be above the parent level class name for the rules underneath it to be formatted, not at a property level.